# Best Practices for Processing After OAuth Login with JWT in SPA

Tags: reactjs, oauth, jwt, single-page-application

I've developed a simple Single Page Application (SPA) website using JWT for authentication, and it's working smoothly. However, I'm encountering challenges when implementing OAuth login. I'd appreciate some guidance on best practices for handling post-OAuth login operations.

To provide context, here's what I have in place:

**1. Signing in with the typical id-password method:**

- The server authenticates the user and returns a JWT.
- The client saves the JWT as follows:

```html
<button onClick={() => {
    const { accessToken, refreshToken } = tryLogin(id, password);
    processLogin(accessToken, refreshToken);
}}>
    Sign in
</button>
```

Nothing special. Is it?

**2. Handling OAuth login:**

After completing the OAuth flow, I'm unsure how to proceed with actually logging in the user in my SPA application. Here's what I have on the server-side (in Python-like pseudo-code), where I've implemented OAuth with Google:

```py
def redirectUriHandler(c: HttpContext):
    # The user is currently on my redirect-uri:
    #
    # http://localhost:3000/login/oauth2/code/google
    #     ?state=...
    #     &code=...

    googleToken = exchangeToken(c.code)
    email = getUserInfo(googleToken)
    user = registerOrLogin(email)
    accessToken, refreshToken = generateJWT(user)

    # What should I do here? How can the React app save these tokens?
```

If I used session, it was super simple: Just set cookie and session store, done!

But due to I'm using SPA, I added a client-side router (React Router) and created an endpoint, `/afteroauth`, where I redirect the user with tokens as query parameters:

```
 def doOAuthLogin(c: HttpContext):
     googleToken = exchangeToken(c.code)
     email = getUserInfo(googleToken)
     user = registerOrLogin(email)
     accessToken, refreshToken = generateJWT(user)
 
+    c.redirect(f"/afteroauth?accessToken={accessToken}&refreshToken={refreshToken}")
```

On the client-side, I have the following code to handle this redirect:

```js
// Client Router /afteroauth
function AfterOAuth() {
    const [params] = userParams();

    processLogin(params.get("accessToken"), params.get("refreshToken"));

    window.location = "/";
}
```

It works, but I'm wondering if it's considered a best practice to:

- add a client-side router solely for this purpose and
- whether it's safe to have tokens in the web history(I don't think so)

Comment: It's a very bad idea to have tokens in the URL. I strongly recommend you try to keep all tokens server-side. If you *do* want the tokens client-side, I made a similar component that does this..maybe it's helpful as an example:  https://github.com/badgateway/react-ketting/blob/main/src/components/RequireLogin.tsx

Answer (score 0):

Answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31682566/how-to-give-user-jwt-token-after-oauth-provider-redirect) says there is no way, but I belive I solved problem at lest about token exposing to web history.

The way is create ticket which hold credential information very short time at server and send the ticket to client, and finally client use that to get real JWT.

But still I need to use client side router.

BEFORE

I sent tokens via query so it remains in browser's history.

```
SERVER                                  CLIENT
====================================    ======================================

response.redirect(
    /afteroauth
        ?accessToken={accessToken}
        &refreshToken={refreshToken}
)

                                        processLogin(
                                            router.getQuery('accessToken')
                                            router.getQuery('refreshToken')
                                        )
```

AFTER

Now I send ticket via query so it remains in browser's history,
but it only valid for 10 seconds and can be used only once so I belive it is safe.

Client use ticket to get JWTs from body.

```
SERVER                                  CLIENT
====================================    ======================================

ticket = UUID()

// valid for 10 secound
volatileStore.push(ticket, userId)
response.redirect(
    /afteroauth
        ?ticket={ticket}
)

                                        ticket = router.getQuery('ticket')
                                        await fetch("/exchange/ticket/{ticket}")

ticket = request.query('ticket')
userId = volatileStore.pop(ticket)
response.body(userStore.findById(userId).generateJWT())

                                        jwt = await fetch("/exchange/ticket/{ticket}")
                                        processLogin(jwt)
```

Comment: Greater! May be reduce time ? 10 seconds too much. There automation that could receive the token too.